# Window Workflow SendReceive Activity timeout issue

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation

I have hosted a state machine Worklow as a WCF service..And the workflow is called in an ASP.NET code. I used netTcpContextBinding for workflow hosting. Problem is that if a SendRecieve activity within the workflow is taking a lot of time (say 1 minute) to execute, then it will show transaction aborted error and will terminate.. i have already set the binding values for send, recieve, open, close timeouts to maximum values in both web.config and the app.config..

How can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TransactionScope has a default timeout of 60 seconds so if whatever you are doing in there takes longer it will time out and abort. You can increase the timeout on the TransactionScope but quite frankly the 60 seconds is already quite long. In most cases you are better of at doing any long running work to collect data before the transaction and keep your transaction time as short as possible.